# Upload file via dropbox API c#

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file as follows:

```
    public async Task UploadDoc()
    {
        using (var dbx = new DropboxClient("my_access_token"))
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Open(@"C:\temp\50203.txt", FileMode.Open))
            {
                await dbx.Files.UploadAsync("/50203.txt", body: fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

and I am getting "System.AggregateException". Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: Look at the inner exception to see what the real exception is.

Comment: You might get more help if you include full Exception message, on what line it occurs and essentialy anything that might be related to the question.

Comment: You seem to have a `Task.Wait()` in your code. Inspect the `AggregateException.InnerException` (or `AggregateException.InnerExceptions`) property. Depending on potential attached child task(s), you may want to use `AggregateException.Flatten()`.